# Composer installation failed "requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages."

Tags: php, package, composer-php

I am trying to install the braunson/fatsecret package with PHP Composer on my local XAMPP installation.
https://packagist.org/packages/braunson/fatsecret-laravel

When I try to install it with the following command:

```
php composer.phar require "braunson/fatsecret:dev-master"
```

The installation fails, and I get the following message:

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of
>   packages.

[image: Installation failed message]

I have installed composer (in my opinion) correctly in `/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/my-folder/` like the documentation says:

```
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
php -r "if (hash_file('SHA384', 'composer-setup.php') === 'e115a8dc7871f15d853148a7fbac7da27d6c0030b848d9b3dc09e2a0388afed865e6a3d6b3c0fad45c48e2b5fc1196ae') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
php composer-setup.php
php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package is called **braunson/fatsecret-laravel**, as per the link you provided to Packagist. Looks like the project's readme is out of date, possibly the package changed names at some point in the past.

You should be able to just change your command to

```
php composer.phar require "braunson/fatsecret-laravel:dev-master"
```